# When looking at skulls from early hominids, how do we know their language creation abilities?

Tags: evolution

If there are no vocal chords left, how do scientists deduce what sounds the specimen was able to create?

Comment: Can you provide us with a specific example of where this happened? Because normally, if they do so, I expect them to describe how they did it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If there are no vocal chords left*

The hyoid bone, which is part of the voice box, does fossilize -- at least occasionally -- and can be used to partially reconstruct the larynx capabilities, so this premise is wrong.

> We now report the discovery of a well-preserved human hyoid bone from Middle Palaeolithic layers of Kebara Cave, Mount Carmel, Israel, dating from about 60,000 years BP. The bone is almost identical in size and shape to the hyoid of present-day populations, suggesting that there has been little or no change in the visceral skeleton (including the hyoid, middle ear ossicles, and inferentially the larynx) during the past 60,000 years of human evolution.

--[A Middle Palaeolithic human hyoid bone](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v338/n6218/abs/338758a0.html)

> The Dikika australopithecine hyoid body proportions are chimpanzeelike.  ... The Kebara hyoid dimensions (body alone, and articulated body and greater horns) are almost all within the observed range for human hyoids. Discriminant functions clearly distinguish human from African ape hyoids and classify the Kebara 2 hyoid as human  ...  the expanded bulla characteristic of the African ape and australopithecine hyoid body is therefore interpreted as reflecting the presence of such a laryngeal air sac extension. Its absence in the human, Neanderthal, and H. heidelbergensis (Atapuerca SH) hyoids implicates the loss of the laryngeal air sacs as a derived Neanderthal and modern human trait ...

--[Comparative Morphology of the Hominin and African Ape Hyoid Bone, a Possible Marker of the Evolution of Speech](http://www.bioone.org/doi/10.3378/027.085.0501?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori:rid:crossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3dpubmed)

> Modelling of the potential acoustic capability of Neanderthal VTs [*vocal tracts*] was carried out by Lieberman et al. [24,25] based on their three-dimensional reconstruction of the La Chapelle-aux-Saints fossil ... A different approach to Neanderthal VT reconstruction was taken by Boë et al. [41] who maintained that the Neanderthal larynx and hyoid bone sat lower in the VT than in Lieberman's reconstruction ... In this paper, we report a new study of the speech potential of Neanderthals, based on reconstructions of the positions of the hyoid and tongue root

--[Articulatory capacity of Neanderthals, a very recent and human-like fossil hominin](http://rstb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/367/1585/88.long)

> The description of a Neanderthal hyoid from Kebara Cave (Israel) in 1989 fuelled scientific debate on the evolution of speech and complex language. Gross anatomy of the Kebara 2 hyoid differs little from that of modern humans. ... Because internal architecture reflects the loadings to which a bone is routinely subjected, our findings are consistent with a capacity for speech in the Neanderthals.

--[Micro-biomechanics of the Kebara 2 hyoid and its implications for speech in Neanderthals.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3867335/)

As well as larynx reconstruction and anatomic evidence, researchers have other lines of evidence about speech capabilities in Neanderthals and other non-modern humans, such as the genetics (especially the gene [FOXP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOXP2)).